How to generate fake names according to country
I am using API to know person IP address and in toaster country name is shown, but I want to generate fake names according to country example if an IP address if of Spain it will detect country name and the names should also be generated according to country name right now I am using toaster plugin for notification example: (fake name according to country) has bought your subscription from Spain (country according to IP address)
this is my controller:
public function index(Request $request) {
    $apiKey = 'Api_key';
    $response = Http::get("##", [
        'apiKey' => $apiKey,
        'ip' => $ip
    ]);

    if ($response->successful()) {
        $country = $response->json()['country_name'];
        Log::info('Country from API: ' . $country);
    } else {
        $country = Faker::create()->country;
        Log::info('API request failed, using random country: ' . $country);
    }
}


You can use this as an example of generating fake names based on country.
$faker = Faker\Factory::create('fr_FR');
$faker->name()
// Luce du Coulon
// Auguste Dupont
// Roger Le Voisin

for spanish, use es_ES.
If you are using Laravel, consider fake('es_ES')->name() for generating a name (or any other faker property) based on locale.
